# How to Manipulate history object?

Tags: javascript, html, browser-history, html5-history

I have Three pages A,B,C. I expect the following navigation.

- Go from page A to Page B.
- Go From Page B to Page C.
- CLick anchor tag in page C to Reach Page B.
- Click on Browser back on Page B has to reach Page A.

But What I am getting is in the Last step on clicking Browser Back on page B taking back to Page C. Again Browser Back in Page C taking back to Page B.Then Browser back in page B taking to page A.

How can I met this usecase.

Comment: This is expected behaviour. browser doesn't care about your navigation that you set in your code. when you hit the back button it will load the previous page that you navigated just before this loaded page

Comment: does page C need to be a page, ie. could it be a `modal` or something that doesnt require a url change?

Comment: @haxxxton No it must be page.